# reduce() function in python does not iterate over input list of numbers

Tags: python, average, reduce

I have a list of numbers:

```
numbers = list(range(1,21,1))
```

and a simple function to calculate average:

```
def average(a_list):
    sum = 0
    for i in a_list:
        sum += i
    return sum/len(a_list)
```

I am attempting to use reduce to find average of my list:

```
from functools import reduce
```

```
reduce(average, numbers)
```

but i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-c930f782df8d> in <module>
----> 1 reduce(average, numbers)

TypeError: average() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Why use `reduce`? Your `average` function, as the error says, only takes a single argument. It is not a valid reduction function. Just pass `numbers` directly to `average`: `average(numbers)`. You could use `reduce` replace your current `average` function, but giving `average` to `reduce` doesn't currently make sense.

Comment: What do you think `reduce` does? `reduce` requires a function with two arguments, yours takes one. Why do you think `reduce` isn't iterating over the list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I realized my mistake, my function average takes one argument whereas a function passed to 'reduce' requires 2. I was trying to understand error statement and was baffled by the fact when did I provide 2 arguments as I had passed one, the list. I realized that the '2' in the error statement referred to first 2 elements of the list and failed when reduce used those two to function average. It makes sense now and purpose of reduce is clear now. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks, it is clear to me now the true purpose of 'reduce'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this. `lambda x,y : x+y` will help us find the sum and `len(list)` will help us divide by the length of the dataset.

```
import functools
numbers = list(range(1,21))
def Average(a_list):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x,y : x+y ,a_list)/len(a_list)
print(Average(numbers))
```

output

```
10.5
```